# In a semiprime right Artinian ring $R$ a finite intersection of maximal ideals is $0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a right artinian semiprime ring $R$ a finite intersection of maximal ideals is $0$.

The definitions I am working with is as follows:

A ring $R$ (associative with $1$) is called *right Artinian* if every decreasing sequence of ideals eventually stabilizes, or equivalently, if every subset of ideals of $R$ has a minimal element.

A ring is called *semiprime* if $0$ is the only nilpotent ideal, or equivalently, the intersection of the prime ideals of $R$ is zero.

A basic result is that if $R$ is right Artinian, then the Jacobson radical $\mathcal{J}(R)$ of $R$ (that is the intersection of all right maximal ideals) is nilpotent ideal (some power of it is zero). From this it follows that in right Artinian ring, the prime radical (the intersection of all prime ideals of $R$) coincides with the Jacobson radical of $R$.

The problem I am having is the following:

Given a right Artinian semiprimitive ring $R$, is it true that there are **finite** number of maximal right ideals $M_1,\dots,M_n$ with $M_1\cap\dots\cap M_n=(0)$.

From the definition of *semiprime* it follows that the prime radical is zero, and because $\mathcal{J}(R)$ coincides with the prime radical, it is also zero. That is, the intersection of **all** right prime ideals of $R$ is zero.

How to get to finite intersections? If we take a look at the set of all finite intersections of maximal right ideals of $R$, this set has a minimal element (because $R$ is right Artinian). Is it true that this element is $(0)$?

Comment: The first sentence of your post is false, as $\mathbb Z$ witnesses.  Do you mean something else?

Comment: "semiprime" means that there are no nonzero nilpotent ideals.  What does "right semiprime" mean? (googleing "right semiprime" yields just this post.)

Comment: Do you mean to require your finite intersections to necessarily have more than one ideal when computing the intersection?

Comment: Thank you, I fixed some of the issues. I forgot to put "Artinian" after right in the title. Also I put the definitions I am working with. I don't think I need to requre the intersections to include more than one ideal, but I'm not quite sure that what I've written is corect also. What I want to achieve is to replace the word "all" in "the intersection of all maximal right ideals with "finite", but I'm not sure if it's correct. If the original set was countable this is true, but I'm not sure in general.

Comment: I guess you mean "**there exists** a finite collection of maximal right ideals intersecting to zero."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question stipulates, we are talking about right Artinian semiprime rings, which are precisely the semisimple Artinian rings.

It is true that the zero ideal is a finite intersection of maximal right ideals.  To see this, note that the ring is a finite direct sum of minimal right ideals, and that the complements of these are maximal right ideals which intersect to zero.

It is not true that any finite intersection of maximal right ideals is zero. For example, if it is not a division ring, then a single maximal ideal does not create a zero intersection.  It is also easy to find counterexamples using two or more right ideals of a square matrix ring.

---

In case you cannot assume this characterization of semisimple rings, then it can also be solved another elementary way (since you mentioned it has to be right Artinian.)

Let's accept the fact you alluded to that the Jacobson radical and prime radical coincide in a right Artinian semiprime ring.

Then we know the intersection of all maximal right ideals is zero.  Suppose for a moment there is no finite collection of maximal right ideals equal to zero.  Under this assumption, any finite intersection is nonzero. Furthermore, for any such collection, one can always add another maximal right ideal which eliminates elements when adding it to the intersection. (Explain why.). By induction, one can define a sequence of maximal right ideals $T_n$ such that $A_n=\cap_{i=0}^n T_n$ is a strictly decreasing sequence of submodules of $R$.  That's a contradiction! (Explain why.)

You may then conclude that the original hypothesis (that no finite collection intersects to 0) was false.

Comment: How do we get that the ring is a finite direct sum of minimal right ideals?  I think I was trying to prove that by getting maximal ideals $M_1,\dots,M_n$ with zero intersection.

Comment: @user3701033 A right artinian semiprime ring is semisimple Artinian, by which I mean _all_ its modules are semisimple, hence representable by direct sums of simple submodules. Any such decomposition of $R$ itself must be finite.

Comment: @user3701033 Are you trying to prove the statement I'm alluding to? if so, I would need to append more information.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to prove that semiprime right Artinian is semiprime (or completely reducible) right Artinian. I managed to prove the other implication (that completely reducible implies right Artinian and semiprime). I was trying to do what you said but in reverce - to prove first that there is a finite intersection of maximal right ideals giving zero and taking complements.

Comment: @user3701033 OK, well as you can see that demonstrates how important it is to give full context to your question. By omitting that you invite many people to contribute the "more obvious" solution that assumes what you are trying to prove.   Next time in a case like this, say "In order prove X, I am trying to prove the following proposition Y."

Comment: @rscwieb yes, you are correct, I apologise. Also, thank you for taking your time explaining to me what I didn't understand and answering my question.